# Google Sheet Auto Email Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a form that contains 84 questions, not all of them are mandatory.

This is the script I manage to write so far:

```
function SendEmail() {

 var ActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

 var StartRow = 2;

 var RowRange = ActiveSheet.getLastRow() - StartRow + 1;

 var WholeRange = ActiveSheet.getRange(StartRow,1,RowRange,84);

 var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues();

 var message = "";
 for (i in AllValues) {

 var CurrentRow = AllValues[i];

 var EmailSent = CurrentRow[85];

 if (EmailSent == "Sent") 
     continue;


# I know this part takes only the first 5 column, I wrote them only as an example. In bold the headers of each column.

  message = 
     "<p><b>Kind of content: </b>" + CurrentRow[2] + "</p>" +
     "<p><b>Project Name: </b>" + CurrentRow[3] + "</p>" +
     "<p><b>Project Description: </b>" + CurrentRow[4] + "</p>" +
     "<p><b>Name of your team: </b>" + CurrentRow[5] + "</p>" +
     "<p><b>Scope of work: </b>" + CurrentRow[6] + "</p>";


  var setRow = parseInt(i) + StartRow;


  ActiveSheet.getRange(setRow, 85).setValue("sent");
}


 var SendTo = "email@gmail.com";

 var Subject = "New"+" " + CurrentRow[2] +" "+"project request";

  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: SendTo,
      cc: "",
      subject: Subject,
      htmlBody: message,
});
}
```

What I want is to send an email every time somebody fills the form and the content of the email should include only the last row and only the columns with data with their header.

The way this script is written will generate an email with 84 rows, most of them empty and not relevant. Can somebody give me a hand with it?

Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you are too naive to coding and Amit is a busy person, so just to help you, I am plugging in the code he has provided to your code with a small correction, so you can just copy the entire code :)

```
function SendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var emailSent = sheet.getRange(lRow, 86).getValue();

  var header = sheet
  .getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn())
  .getDisplayValues()[0];

  if (emailSent != "Sent"){
    var data = sheet
    .getRange(lRow,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn())
    .getDisplayValues()[0];
    var output = [];
    for (var d=0; d<data.length; d++) {
      if (data[d] !== "") {
        output.push(header[d] + " = " + data[d]);    
      }
    }
    var message = output.join("\n");
    var SendTo = "email@gmail.com";
    var Subject = "New"+" " + sheet.getRange(lRow, 3).getValue() +" "+"project request";
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: SendTo,
      cc: "",
      subject: Subject,
      htmlBody: message,
    });
    sheet.getRange(lRow, 86).setValue("sent");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Alpesh, thank you so much for your help! Indeed I'm a completely noobie, but I can read your code and understand what every function does and how they interact with each other. The output though is not in different lines, the output.join("\n") should create a new line for any data right?

Comment: the output.join("\n") will add a new line to each element of the array. So there will be a new line after each column header and value entry.

Comment: I replaced the "\n" for <br/> and got what I need :)    I figured it out how to set the header in bold too, so now the email looks exactly how I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sheet.getLastRow()` to get the index of the last row in the sheet that has data.

For finding columns that have data, you can iterate through the row data and look for cell values that are not blank.

```
var header = sheet
             .getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn())
             .getDisplayValues()[0];


var data = sheet
             .getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,sheet.getLastColumn())
             .getDisplayValues()[0];

var output = [];

for (var d=0; d<data.length; d++) {
  if (data[d] !== "") {
    output.push(header[d] + " = " + data[d]);    
  }
}

return data.join("\n");
```

Comment: Hi Amit, where exactly should I include this code?? How the whole script will look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter, for example

```
var AllValues = WholeRange.getValues().filter( row => row[5] != '');
```

will reduce AllValues to only those there column 6 isn't empty

Comment: Hi roma, thanks for the tip, but that would not solve the problem with the headers, right?

Comment: Amit's answer is more verbose version which should do the trick...